# Internet Explorer modo Padrões

Tags: internet-explorer

Existe alguma forma de "forçar" o Internet Explorer e renderizar um site no modo "Padrões" ? Poderiam me informar alguma leitura correspondente a esse assunto?

Answer (score 3):

A maneira mais simples, não só no IE mas em qualquer browser, é usar o doctype do HTML5 no topo do seu documento:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Em algumas situações, o modo de compatibilidade do navegador pode estar habilitado por padrão.

Não sei se é somente na empresa que trabalho, mas aqui os sites de intranet são carregados no modo de compatibilidade por padrão, mesmo que o doctype esteja definido corretamente.

Para forçar o IE a renderizar a página no modo "Padrões", mesmo que a opção de usar compatibilidade esteja ativada no cliente, use a meta tag/header `X-UA-Compatible`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" >
```

A opção `IE=Edge` força a utilizar os padrões mais recentes.

Mais informações sobre as opções disponíveis podem ser encontradas [aqui](https://web.archive.org/web/20150722045303/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/luisdem/archive/2013/07/18/modos-de-compatibilidade-do-internet-explorer.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Complementando as respostas acima, na verdade podem existir várias razões que levam um site a não ser exibido no modo padrões. Dentre elas temos:

- Não usar `<!DOCTYPE html>`
- Especificar a tag meta `X-UA-Compatible` com content tendo valor para um determinado documento mode que não seja o Edge (eg. IE8, IE9, etc).
- Ter meu site no Compatibility View List da minha máquina, ou da minha empresa ou da Microsoft.
- Ter meu Internet Explorer configurado para acessar páginas na Intranet com *Compatibility View* (acessar Configurações da lista de compatibilidade do Internet Explorer)
- Usar recursos como Flash e ActiveX.

A microsoft disponibiliza, através do [dev.modern.ie](http://dev.modern.ie) a ferramenta [Site scan](http://dev.modern.ie/tools/staticscan/) que permite analisar seu site e apontar possíveis problemas e sugestões de melhoria. Lá você pode encontrar soluções para atualizar o seu site e garantir que ele será visualizado usando o documento mode Edge.

Para mais detalhes, nesse [link](http://talkitbr.com/2015/08/24/como-fazer-o-ie-exibir-melhor-o-meu-site/) eu detalho esse assunto.